# Unable to set variable enumerator in for each loop container SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, foreach-loop-container

I tried to choose Foreach From Variable Enumerator, but this Message thrown
in for eachloop container set:

[image]

What Im trying to achieve:
execute a script task (run succesfully) to put list object to dtsVariable (Object type) and then use the same variable to run in the foreach loop container.

Answer (score 0):

You could store your list as a variable of Datatype 'Object' in SSIS.  Then you could use a Foreach ADO Enumerator in the Foreach loop container to increment the variable.

If this is a helpful idea it is explained in depth at the link below:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS